# Java regex match with error due to $

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex snippet to parse the URL of an ahref as follow:

```
(?<=href=)[^\"']+(?=(\"|'))?>
```

What I m trying to do is replace the following snippet with data, i populate at runtime:

```
<a href=$tracking_url$&langding_url=google.com>
   <img src="irreleavnt" />
</a>
```

When i try replaceAll() as follows, it fails

```
 String fragment = <a href=$click_tracking_url$&landing_url=google.com><img src=\"10.gif\" /></a>
 String processedFragment = fragment.replaceAll(AHREF_REGEX, ahrefurl);
```

The error is :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:724)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:824)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:1572)
```

How can i fix the regex to match `<a href=$click_tracking_url$` ? How can i escape `$` from regex?

Comment: I think quantifying lookaround assertions leads to undefined behavior. I'm confused though. What is the point of asserting anyway if you're gonna make it optional...? (I'm talking about ``(?=...)?``.)

Comment: i m not making optional. $tracking_url$ is read from a file and will be replaced with the tracking_url at a different service. $tracking_url$ is not being used for any regex.

Comment: I don't think the failure has anything to do with the ``$``, to be honest. I think the problem is that you're applying the quantifier ``?`` to a zero-width assertion ``(?=...)``. Plus, are you sure the rest of the regex makes sense? You're looking for a string of non-quote characters that is preceded by ``href=`` and followed by a (presumably) closing quote character, to one that was never opened...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. I tried your regexp and didn't get the error. However, the regexp didn't replace the `$click_tracking_url$` but the whole text until the end of the element.

In case you need to dynamically replace placeholders, try something like this:

```
Map<String, String> placeholders = new HashMap<String, String>();
// init your placeholders somehow...
placeholders.put("click_tracking_url", "something");

String fragment = "<a href=\"$click_tracking_url$&landing_url=google.com\"><img src=\"10.gif\" /></a>";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\$(\\w+)\\$").matcher(fragment);
if (m.find()) { 
   String processedFragment = m.replaceAll(placeholders.get(m.group(1)));
   System.out.println(processedFragment);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, give this a shot. Replace this...

```
(?<=href=)(['"]?)\\$([^$>]+)\\$
```

...with this:

```
$1$url
```

And don't forget to escape your backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to replace patterns in the form of `$someIdentifier$` with some value in your application you're using someIdentifier to dereference.

It seems you would want to use the pattern `\$([^\$]+)\$` and find each occurrence in the string, grab the value of group one (1), look up the value and then replace all occurrences of that specific sequence with the value you looked up.

```
   String someString = "some$string$withatoken";
   Pattern tokenPattern = Pattern.compile("\\$([^\\$]+)\\$");
   Matcher tokenMatcher = tokenPattern.matcher(someString);
   // find not matches.  matches will compare the entire string against the pattern
   // basically enforcing ^{pattern}$.
   while (tokenMatcher.find()) {
       String tokenName = tokenMatch.group(1);
       String tokenValue = tokenMap.get(tokenName); // lookup value of token name.
       someString = someString.replaceAll("\\$" + tokenName + "\\$", tokenValue);

       // resets the target of the matcher with the new value of someString.
       tokenMatcher.reset(someString);
   }
```